# Caught deadly signal TRAP on PlugInstall

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-plugin

I've been using [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) for a while, but suddenly today when I ran `:PlugInstall`, vim exited with

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal TRAP
Vim: Finished.
```

I commented out the plugin I had just added and was still getting that result. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research, there's a related [Github Issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23938) on homebrew that referred to problems with mismatched Ruby versions for vim and its plugins and suggests switching to system ruby, uninstalling vim, reinstalling it with `brew uninstall vim; rvm system; brew install vim`. I didn't run this, but instead ran `brew update; brew upgrade` before I intended to, and just that fixed the issue. The upgrade did upgrade vim, which may have fixed it by recompiling vim with my current ruby. My issue may have been unrelated to that one though, hard to be sure.